# Using a shorter heatbreak on the Anet A6

Tags: anet-a6, heat-break

I need to replace my heatbreak on my Anet A6 since I pushed out the PTFE tube when my filament got clogged...

The current heatbreak has a length of 40 mm, but, the shop I'm buying from only sells the 30 mm or 35 mm (the 40 mm is out of stock).

Can I just install a 35 mm heatbreak? Or even a 30 mm? Or is the 40 mm crucial in the design of the Anet A6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hotend design is called a Mk8 type/style hotend, based on the Mk8 Makerbot design. You should get the 40 mm length heatbreak, this option gives you some extra space, a shorter heatbreak will result in changing the Z-endstop height or raise the bed (if the endstop is fixed).

[image]

The 30 mm will for sure be too short and result in a gap in the heat conducting element, the 35 mm might work. You can source the heatbreaks from typical online market places for about a dollar you get 5 pieces, order these while you try if the 35 mm version works for you (depending on endstop and bed).

Comment: Thank you for your considerations. I have a BLtouch to probe the bed. This will mean that I need to adjust the Z-offset when I'm going to try the 35 mm. I do need to check if the BLtouch will be high enough for this Z-offset

Comment: @zwep Yes, in case you have a touch sensor you need a different bracket or move the sensor up and redefine the Z-offset.